# DataGrid Horizontal Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Title may be mistaken, but not, please keep reading.

I need a dynamic datagrid, so I'm creating the columns by using this method which gets the "selected" columns to display:

```
    public void ConfigureGridColumns()
    {
        App.Instance.MainWindow.grdDetail.mainGrd.Columns.Clear();

        var stats = new List<Statistic>();
        stats.AddRange(App.Instance.Manager.PersonalizeStatistics.OrderBy(x => x.Index).Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Statistic));

        foreach (var stat in stats)
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = stat.Name,
                Binding = new Binding(stat.Key)
            };
        }
    }
```

Now, I DO NOT WANT to create a model that contains ALL the columns, because I have more than 150 dynamic columns.

So I'm dynamically generating the ItemsSource by building a custom DataTable where row's column is mapped by the key like previous:

```
        private void ConfigureGridSource()
        {
        var dt = new DataTable("stats");

        foreach (var player in App.Instance.Manager.Players.Values.Take(5))
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (var stat in stats)
            {
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(stat.Statistic.Key))
                    t.Columns.Add(stat.Statistic.Key, typeof(StatisticPersonalizedValue));

                var persStat = new StatisticPersonalizedValue(stat);
                persStat.Value = player.Statistics[stat.Statistic.Key];

                row[stat.Statistic.Key] = persStat;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        grdDetail.mainGrd.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt.DefaultView);
        }
```

Issue is that:

with

```
        Binding = new Binding(stat.Key)
```

I get the namespace of StatisticPersonalizedValue as text

with

```
        Binding = new Binding("Value")
```

I get empty string (Value is the property of StatisticPersonalizedValue which is being valued in the second method)

I'm using models because I also have setters for positive and negative values in case, do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: An off topic comment, please dont use Var when you actually know the type of the object, e.g youve got a var thats always a datatable, a var thats always a row, a var thats always a statisticpersonalisedvalue...

Comment: @RhysW I disagree. What if you have a `KeyValuePair<MyVeryLongNameClass,MyOtherVeryLongNameClass>`? It creates a lot of unecessary clutter in the code. I prefer to use var.

Comment: It may create clutter in some instances (and this can typically be avoided by proper code formatting), but it is generally bad coding practice for several reasons, one of which is that it is more difficult for other people to follow your code when you ask for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed that.

I had to add a custom converter

```
Binding = new Binding(stat.Key) { Converter = new StatisticPersonalizedValueConverter() }



public class StatisticPersonalizedValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is StatisticPersonalizedValue)
        {
            return (value as StatisticPersonalizedValue).Value;
        }
        return string.Empty;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This did the trick.